# When and why do I get a copy when initializing a reference?

Tags: c++, reference

There are cases when I want a reference to an object but instead I get a copy.
Here is an example:

```
  std::pair<const std::string, int> foo("hello", 5);
  const std::pair<std::string, int> & bar = foo;

  std::cout << "foo: " << foo.first << " " << foo.second << std::endl;
  std::cout << "bar: " << bar.first << " " << bar.second << std::endl;
  foo.second = 7;
  std::cout << "foo: " << foo.first << " " << foo.second << std::endl;
  std::cout << "bar: " << bar.first << " " << bar.second << std::endl;
```

This produces:

```
foo: hello 5
bar: hello 5
foo: hello 7
bar: hello 5
```

So apparently a copy of `foo` has been created while the syntax suggests (to me at least) that the programmer wanted a reference to it.
This violates the principle that a reference should be an alias to something. It would be great if somebody could explain what is going on and why.

(Note: I came across this [here](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3853.htm))

Comment: The types are different.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The underlying types of `foo` and `bar` are different, so a temporary is created using an implicit conversion from the type on the RHS to the one on the LHS<sup>*</sup>. The C++ standard allows for a `const` reference to bind to a temporary and extend its lifetime.

The `const` reference `bar` binds to that temporary, which is a distinct object from `foo`.

If you were to use the same types, you'd get the result you expect:

```
std::pair<const std::string, int> foo("hello", 5);
const std::pair<const std::string, int> & bar = foo;
```

or

```
std::pair<std::string, int> foo("hello", 5);
const std::pair<std::string, int> & bar = foo;
```

would yield

```
foo: hello 5
bar: hello 5
foo: hello 7
bar: hello 7
```

---

<sup>*`std::pair` has a [template constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair) that allows this implicit conversion from one type of pair to another.</sup>

Comment: And in which cases will assigning incompatible types create a temporary as opposed to just throwing a compiler error?

Comment: @Sarien There needs to be a valid conversion between `T1` and `T2` in `const T2& = T1`;

Comment: @Sarien the compiler looks for a viable conversion. It can invoke the constructor of `pair` with copies of the value in the original pair, so it will do.

Comment: @juanchopanza Okay, so different types will lead to copies when a valid conversion exists and to an error otherwise. Good. Now I see, that my case will lead to a copy because it compiles and the types are different. Is there anything I should know from memory about when these conversions exist?

Comment: @Sarien I think you need to remember that if the types are different you need an *implicit* conversion. If there isn't one, you'll get a compiler error. Then, you should know the classes you are using. For example, this [`std::pair` constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair) shows a template constructor that allows for the implicit conversion from a different type of pair.

Comment: @Sarien Note also that your code wouldn't have compiled if the reference variable `bar` was not `const`. Non-const references are forbidden to bind to unnamed temporaries [for very similar reasons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763398/why-is-it-illegal-to-take-the-address-of-an-rvalue-temporary/9779765#9779765).

Comment: To emphasis the example for `bar` to be the same type, you could use `const auto & bar = foo;`. That's a purpose of the keyword, to prevent unwanted implicit conversion.

Answer (score 5):

That's a special property of references to `const` (and of rvalue refereneces, naturally). These references can bind to temporary objects.

Notice that `std::pair<const std::string, int>` (the type of `foo`) is a different type than `std::pair<std::string, int>` (the type to which `bar` wants to refer, modulo `const`). There is no object of type `std::pair<std::string, int>` in your code, so `bar` cannot bind to any such object.

However, as I said, references to `const` and rvalue references can bind to temporaries. And an object of type `std::pair<std::string, int>` can be implicitly created from an object of type `std::pair<const std::string, int>`. Therefore, such a temporary object is created, and `bar` is bound to that temporary. This reference binding also extends the lifetime of the temporary to that of `bar`<sup>*</sup>.

That's why you get a copy. If you changed the type of `bar` to `std::pair<std::string, int> &` (i.e. dropped the `const`), you'd instead get a compilation error that a non-const lvalue reference cannot bind to a temporary.

---

<sup>*</sup> In the special case of a member variable of reference type bound to a temporary, the temporary's lifetime will only extend until the end of the constructor which initialised the reference.