# lvalue required as unary '&' operand in c++11

Tags: c++, ostream

I'm coding c++11.
In a class A, I have a  **member variable** "member" which is defined as

```
vector<OtherClass> member; // A's member variable
```

I would like to serialize  A ( so I want to all the data type in OtherClass contained in the vector ) into file in binary format so I defined a function write as follows.

```
void A::write(ostream& os){ // A's function for outputting A
   os.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>( &(member.size()) ), sizeof(member.size()));
}
```

But compiler said lvalue required as unary '&' operand.

How can I fix it without creating a temporary object such as long size=member.size() in the write function?

Comment: Please make it clear what the exact error message you're getting.

Comment: This looks unfortunate but impossible to me to achieve without a local.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to write to `os`?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763398/why-is-it-illegal-to-take-the-address-of-an-rvalue-temporary

Comment: You are stuck making a temporary as you need an lvalue. Just bite the bullet and do it.  If you have a really cool compiler it could even optimize that away and if not copying a 4/8 bytes is not going to be a big deal.  The I/O is so heavy you'll never notice a single copy.

Comment: `ostream` is for formatting things into a character sequence. Why are you (or anybody for that matter) using it for binary?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `&(member.size())` - you're not assigning size()'s return value and trying to take the address of it (it may not even have an address).

But no idea why you're calling size here anyway you need the start address of the actual data: `member.data()` (or if you dont have C++11 `&member[0]`)

Comment: When you `write` a vector you need to write it's `size` and then its `data` otherwise you will not know how much to `read` back in.

Comment: @virgesmith The OP wants to serialize vector. Anyway he will need to write both data and size. To write size using `ostream.write` method, one needs to know both address and size of what is being written - the address and size of the `size()` return value.

Comment: ostream& write (const char* s, streamsize n);See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/write/ i.e in this case `os.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(member.data()), member.size() * sizeof(OtherClass))`.

Comment: @virgesmith As you have lower rep, you will not be able to see that I already deleted the same answer, based on a similar comment from alexeykuzmin0; it seems that in this case, the asker is actually first trying to serialize the *size* of the vector (and will presumably serialize the contents next).

Comment: don't forget the dubious `sizeof(member.size())` ;)

Answer (score 1):

"How can I fix it without creating a temporary object"

You can't. You want to use `&`, which takes the address of an object. No object, no address. It's really that simple.

<sub>Note that your `long size = member.size()` idea doesn't create a *temporary* variable. That's an ordinary variable.</sub>